# "Linked" questions shows a link from a deleted answer

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, deleted-answers, linked-questions

I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27266356/1714410). [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266654/1714410) contained a link to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023171/variable-appears-to-change-size-on-every-loop-iteration-what?lq=1). Once this linked question was detected in my answer, the "Linked Questions" sidebar showed this question - as expected.

Soon enough I understand my answer was incorrect so I deleted it.
However, the link appearing at the "Linked Questions" side bar was **not** removed, despite the fact that the answer that created this link in the first place was removed.

I believe this is a bug: if an answer (or a comment at that) linking to another SO post is removed, that link should no longer be reflected in the "Linked questions" sidebar.